# Occurred Exception for Android 6.0, When I use checkSelfPermission

Tags: java, android

I am trying to apply permission in Android 6.0(Marshmallow).

But I have below issue.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkPermission(java.lang.String, int, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.checkPermission(ContextWrapper.java:637)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ContextCompat.java:387)
        at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.VSFunctionActivity.Scan(VSFunctionActivity.java:530)
        at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.VSFunctionActivity.GetPairedList(VSFunctionActivity.java:519)
```

The following codes are part of the problem.

```
public void Scan(int scantime)
{
    // Scan function
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Variable.mb_Debug) {
            Log.i(Variable.TAG, "Location permissions has NOT been granted. Requesting permissions.");
        }
        requestLocationPermission();
    }
```

VSFunctionActivity's line 530 is 
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

I already changed minSdkVersion to "23" from "18". But I can't fix it.

I use Android Studio 1.4 beta2.

Do you have any solution or idea?
Please share your knowledge.

Regards

Comment: Have you added this to your build.gradle? `com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1`

Comment: because you forgot to add if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) // Scan function
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Variable.mb_Debug) {
            Log.i(Variable.TAG, "Location permissions has NOT been granted. Requesting permissions.");
        }
        requestLocationPermission();

Comment: I already add "compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'". And I add "if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)". But I have problem yet.

Comment: See this link for more information https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html